# Ubuntu 18.04: Different logo at startup and different lock-screen

Tags: 18.04, startup, ubuntu-gnome, lock-screen, logo

I had been using Gnome on Ubuntu 16.04 instead of the usual Unity. When I updated to 18.04, this weird double u's logo persisted through the upgrade and now both of my home and lock screens are different.

[Startup logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDKVJ.jpg)

[Lock screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGnGI.png)

[Lock screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwU0t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's GNOME. It's a little different from what you're used to in 16.04. What you're seeing is the GNOME splash (boot/welcome) screen, and gdm3 login screen.

`ls -al /etc/alternatives/*plymouth*` # shows what the splash screen is currently set to.

You can change it back to the old-school Ubuntu splash screens using the `update-alternatives` command. See `man update-alternatives` for help.

If you're running with gdm3 display manager, and you wish to run lightdm instead, you can `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.

But... I'd recommend leaving this all alone, and just take some time to get used to the new look.

Comment: Thanks. Changing it to gdm3 worked. I had forgotten that I had switched the display managers.